# mongodb group and sum?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been bumping my head over this for the past few hours and can't wrap my head around it. Maybe someone can help. I have a collection with the following.

```
{
    "smallparts": [
        { "quantity": "10", "part": "test1" },
        { "quantity": "10", "part": "test2" }
    ]
},
{
    "smallparts": [
        { "quantity": "10", "part": "test3" }
    ]
},
{
    "smallparts": [
        { "quantity": "10", "part": "test1" },
        { "quantity": "10", "part": "test2" }
    ]
}
```

When trying the following to add the quantity I can't get right.

```
collection.aggregate(    

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind":"$smallparts" },

    // Group the products
    {
      "$group":
      {
         "_id":
         {
            "part": "$smallparts.part",
            "total": "$smallparts.quantity",
         }
      },
   },
```

My output is this which is wrong. test1 and test2 should be 20.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "part": "test3",
            "total": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "part": "test2",
            "total": "10"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "part": "test1",
            "total": "10"
        }
    }
]
```

}

I also tried this but get an empty array.

> collection.aggregate(
>       // Unwind the array
>       { "$unwind":"$smallparts" },
>
> ```
> // Group the products
> {
>   "$group":
>   {
>      "_id":
>      {
>         "part": "$smallparts.part",
>         "total": "$smallparts.quantity",
>          sum: { $sum: "$smallparts.quantity" }
>      }
>   },
> ```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you can't use `$sum` with strings. You will need to convert your quantity to integer for this query to work.

The way to get the sum of all total's grouped by part when quantity is an integer:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { $unwind : "$smallparts"},
    { $group : { 
        _id : "$smallparts.part" , 
         sum :  { $sum : "$smallparts.quantity" } 
    } 
}]);
```

If you have control over the db schema this would be the recommended approach.

The second approach is to rewrite your query using map-reduce where you can use JavaScript functions like `parseInt` to convert the values:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    for (var idx = 0; idx < this.smallparts.length; idx++) {
        emit(this.smallparts[idx].part, this.smallparts[idx].quantity);
    }
};

var reduceFunction = function(key, vals) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var idx = 0; idx < vals.length; idx++) {
        sum += parseInt(vals[idx]);
    }
    return sum;
};

db.coll.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, { out : "my_mapreduce_res"});
```

Your map-reduce results will be stored in the `my_mapreduce_res` collection.